# After signin to IdentityServer a redirectUrl route doesn't open method, but returns POST 302

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid

.Net Core 3.1

Nginx reverse proxy.

**My custom callback url works, but doesn't load in Mvc Client controller method. It's very strange.**

MVC client login into IdentityServer and after that IdentityServer redirects to previous Url. For example authorize link is /Home/Privacy. After success login I will be redirect to this page. It's good.

But I want get this schema:

1. Mvc Client (from /Home/Privacy) signin with IdentityServer.
2. After that IdentityServer redirects to url signin-callback, where Mvc Client route call to controller method SignedIn and do work.
3. SignedIn redirects to previous url (/Home/Privacy).

**I have problem with the second step.**

**MVC Client**

AccountController.cs

```
[HttpPost("signin-callback")]
 public IActionResult SignedIn()
 {
    _cache.SetString("message", "Good day!");
    Console.WriteLine("<<< Ok >>>");

    return View();
 }
```

Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";

            })
                .AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
                {
                    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;                  
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
                    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                })
                .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
                {

                    options.Authority = $"{OpenId["Url"]}/auth";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.ClientId = OpenId["ClientId"];
                    options.ClientSecret = OpenId["ClientSecret"];
                    options.ResponseType = "code";
                    options.UsePkce = true;
                    options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

                    options.CallbackPath = "/signin-callback";
                    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                    options.Scope.Clear();
                    options.Scope.Add("openid");
                    options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
                    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("website", "website");
                    options.SaveTokens = true;
                    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                    {

                        OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = ctx =>
                        {
                            ctx.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = "http://address.com/editor/signin-callback";
                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        },



                        OnTicketReceived = (e) =>
                       {
                           e.Properties.IsPersistent = true;
                           e.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(60);
                           return Task.CompletedTask;
                       }
                    };

                });
       services.AddControllersWithViews();
......
}

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
 {
   app.UsePathBase("/editor");
   app.UseStaticFiles();

   app.UseRouting();

   app.UseAuthentication();
   app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
 }
```

**IdentityServer**

Config.cs

```
new Client
{
      ClientId = ...,
      ClientName = ...,
      ClientSecrets = { ...},

      AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.CodeAndClientCredentials,
      RequireConsent = false,
      RequirePkce = true,
      FrontChannelLogoutSessionRequired = false,
      IdentityTokenLifetime = 300,
      AccessTokenLifetime = 1200,
      AuthorizationCodeLifetime = 300,
      AllowedCorsOrigins = {
                        "http://address.com"
      },


    RedirectUris = {
             "http://address.com/editor/signin-callback"                       
   },


   PostLogoutRedirectUris = {
                        ....
                    },
 AllowOfflineAccess = true,
 AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
 AllowedScopes = new List<string>
 {
       IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
       IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile

 }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
 ....


services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
            {
                config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
            })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


 var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
                options.Cors.CorsPaths.Add("/Account/AntiForgery");
                options.Cors.CorsPaths.Add("/Account/Login");
                options.Cors.CorsPaths.Add(null);
....
services.AddAuthentication();
....
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                // this defines a CORS policy called "default"
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", policy =>
                {

                    policy.WithOrigins("http://address.com")
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowCredentials();
                });
            });

            })
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
            app.UsePathBase("/auth");
...
}
```

After login IdentityServer redirects to previous page. But what is wrong with signin-callback url?
In Chrome:
[image]

I think signin-callback has to load SignedIn method. But in server logs I don't see my mark <<< Ok >>>, and cache is empty.
When I write wrong url

```
[HttpPost("signin-callback_what-is-wrong")]
```

Nothing changes. Always Chrome/Nginx in logs writes POST 302 0. 
I checked this url on HttpGet: address.com/editor/signin-callback. And always get in logs <<< Ok >>>.

This like not real virtual redirect.

I feel like idiot. Two days on this problem - but no results...
I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have this method?

```
[HttpPost("signin-callback")]
public IActionResult SignedIn()
```

And have this middleware?

```
OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = ctx =>
{
    ctx.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = "http://address.com/editor/signin-callback";
    return Task.FromResult(0);
},
```

This is all handled by IdentityServer, so I think you should remove it.

In my application I have a login button that has a returnurl parameter. When clicked it calls the following method. It doesn't enter it because it's secured. So the user is first automatically redirected to IdentityServer and the method is only accessed when login was succesful. Having persisted the return url, the user is redirected back to the page where it came from.

```
[Authorize]
public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(returnUrl))
        return LocalRedirect($"~/");

    return LocalRedirect($"~{returnUrl}");
}
```

Comment: You have login button. I understand. But in my case  I don't have login button. I need to open secured /Home/Privacy link. I need that user will be redirected to IdentityServer (now it works), and then there needs to redirect for example in your Login method. Login method will add cache and redirects to previous page. How I can this handle?